# Prevent loading view unless authenticated

Tags: javascript, angularjs, session, servlets, frontend

I am new to angularJS.

I have a login page. I have made sessions using servlets.

But when user manipulates the url and hits enter then the servlet is getting called asynchronously and backend checks whether session is active or not.

If user is not logged in , then it gives a pop-up saying "You need to login first."

But the problem is that the template corresponding to that url is loaded first and then the pop-up comes.

I want the user to stay on the login page itself and give a popup on the same page even if he/she tries to change url.

Is it possible with angular to call the servlet first and then if "success" then load the view?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just redirect to login page instead of a popup. Popups are ugly

Comment: Yes. i redirected it to login page. But for a second it loads the other template unless the backend returns a response and then it comes back to login page.

Comment: Is the redirect the first thing you do in the controller?

Comment: I do the redirect if the authentication fails. i.e. in the sucess condition i check what the backend returns. if it returns false then i.e the session is not active then i redirect it to login page. So till that response comes, it has already loaded the template.

Comment: I see. How are you getting the session? Cookie or database call?

Comment: I am using  HttpSession session=request.getSession(false);

Comment: Ok right. You should store it in a cookie so you don't have to make a request every time. To test this quickly you could store the session in rootScope. ONLY FOR TEST PURPOSES THOUGH.

Comment: Actually cookies can be deleted right? And it is an app which i am building for official use. So can you suggest a long term approach?

Comment: cookies can be deleted but its safe to use them on your app because you wont be able to delete them like on a browser. Like if you wanted to get the app data removed you should be logged out by deleting the cookie on your device.